# How to embed local .xcframework to Flutter IOS plugin?

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins

I'm totally new in IOS development, so I only have basic knowledge on how Pod/Podspec, but I don't really know how it works

Basically I have this flutter plugin project that uses external dependency in .aar(android) and .xcframework(iOS). I wanted to embed this .xcframework into my plugin, so I imported the file into my ios plugin directory, and add it in the Framework & Library in xcode.

But when I use the plugin in my app flutter project, the library in .xcframework is not recognized, unless I do the same thing again, which is importing the .xcframework file, and add it to Framework & Library in xcode...

I tried to set the `Embed` options to `Embed & Sign` and `Embed without Signing`, does not work!

Can I just embed the .xcframework in the plugin, so other project can simply add the plugin in the pubspec and works, just like .aar in Android library? Thank you